# Freemodbus on PIC18F with MPLAB X XC8

Tags: modbus, xc8

I'm trying to adapt the freemodbus library into a microcontroller PIC18F from microchip, on the MPLAB X ide and XC8 compiler.

I've corrected as much as I could and currently the problems that I have are about sintaxis,

I wonder if somebody can help me with the next issues, on my files I've done the types declarations to match with my compiler, like UCHAR = uint8...

In the file [mbframe.h](http://www.sourceboost.com/Products/BoostC/ExampleCode/Modbus/html/modbus/include/mbframe.h.html)

```
typedef eMBErrorCode( *peMBFrameReceive ) ( UCHAR * pucRcvAddress, UCHAR ** pucFrame, USHORT * pusLength );
```

I'm getting the error:

> modbus/functions/../includes/mbframe.h:77: error: (194) ")" expected

The parameters are being defined there (pucRcvAddress, pucFrame, pusLength ) ok?

About peMBFrameReceive I think it's declared in the file [mb.c](http://ucxpresso.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/nano1768/uCXpresso/extensions/lib/modbus/mb.c/):

```
static peMBFrameReceive peMBFrameReceiveCur;
```

It has not an error but a warning

> modbus/mb.c:65: warning: (374) missing basic type; int assumed

And in the mb.h

```
    /*! \ingroup modbus
 * \brief Errorcodes used by all function in the protocol stack.
 */
typedef enum {
    MB_ENOERR, /*!< no error. */
    MB_ENOREG, /*!< illegal register address. */
    MB_EINVAL, /*!< illegal argument. */
    MB_EPORTERR, /*!< porting layer error. */
    MB_ENORES, /*!< insufficient resources. */
    MB_EIO, /*!< I/O error. */
    MB_EILLSTATE, /*!< protocol stack in illegal state. */
    MB_ETIMEDOUT /*!< timeout error occurred. */
} eMBErrorCode;
```

What I understand is that "typedef eMBErrorCode(..." is the definition and "static ..." is the declaration.

And it cannot find the type "peMBFrameReceive", becasuse it has an error, so do you know whats wrong with the definition?

Thanks and my best regards